# Add file with TortoiseSVN and Github

Tags: svn, github

I am using TortoiseSVN as a Windows client for my Github repository. I am creating a brand new repository with readme.md file and cheking it out to local directory. Then I create new text file 111.txt with some content in \trunk folder. Then I issue TortoiseSVN Add command and try to commit. I receive following error message:

```
D:\Work\DXF\cadlib_1\trunk\111.txt
D:\Work\DXF\cadlib_1\trunk\111.txt
Commit failed (details follow):
File 'D:\Work\DXF\cadlib_1\trunk\111.txt' is out of date
Path '/ar-info/cadlib.git/!svn/wrk/23192872-a0c9-7044-87ea-c7fad1a69310/trunk/111.txt'
already exists
You have to update your working copy first.
```

If I do svn update before commit the result is the same. Does anyone have an idea what is the problem?

TortoiseSVN 1.9.0, Build 26652 - 64 Bit , 2015/08/03 19:33:09; OS - Windows 7 Enterprise SP1

I have checked how it works with repository stored on another server (not github) - everything works fine.

Comment: Unrelated, but - "downgrade TSVN to 1.8.*, SVN 1.9 is **very buggy**"

Comment: TortoiseSVN 1.8.12, Build 26645 - 64 Bit , 2015/08/02 15:51:39 - everything works great. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score -1):

I can confirm the latest 1.9 TortiseSVN has issues with SVN hosting on Github. The best way is to download back to 1.8.